# How do i grab everything inside the BODY html tag (From a string) using RegEx Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

{Yup, the above more or less explains it} :)

`Regex oRegex = new Regex("<body.*?>(.*?)</body>", RegexOptions.Multiline);`

The above doesnt seem to work if the body has any attributes in it.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input that fails to match?

Answer (score 10):

With the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) (assuming it is html, not xhtml):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
string body = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body").InnerHtml;
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, i'm gonna try the xmldoc route, and if that fails then go with the agility pack.

Comment: Just a heads up, HtmlAgilityPack does not support compact framework 3.5

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a regular expression. Use something that's meant to parse XML/HTML:

```
XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//body").InnerXml;
```

Load your string into an [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument_members.aspx), use the [SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectsinglenode.aspx) function (which takes an [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp) expression as a parameter), then extract what you need from the resulting [XmlNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode_members.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I solved it eventually by using `RegexOptions.Singleline` instead of using `RegexOptions.Multiline`